# Java Drag and drop

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to the drag and drop features of java and I wanted to know if it is possible to drag and drop a short-cut from the desktop on a java jpanel and get info from it like icon .exe location and so on. I only found tutorials for text images and other java objects.

Comment: 1) *"I only found tutorials for text images and other java objects."*  What happened when you tried to adapt them?  Where is your best attempt?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
2) For such 'platform specific' functionality, it is generally better to look to a language developed for that platform.  E.G. '.Net'.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the file and all the data that Java is able to acquire about a File.

But I believe you cannot get icon.